# I have two array, one have N no of data and and another have fixed no of data

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two array, one with n of data and 2nd array with fixed no of data which includes 5-6 color

Example :

Array 1 =>

```
const category = [
{
  name: 'Groceries',
  icon: ICONS.GROCERY,
},
{
  name: 'Bakery',
  icon: ICONS.BAKERY,
},
{
  name: 'General Stores',
  icon: ICONS.GENERAL_STORE,
},
{
  name: 'Cafe & Food',
  icon: ICONS.CAFE,
},
{
  name: 'Apparels',
  icon: ICONS.APPARELS,
},

 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .

];
```

Array 2 =>

```
 const bgColor = ['red', 'pink', 'blue', 'green'];
```

I want to merge 2 array, means i want to add background color to 1st array (category), when 2nd array elements complete its starts again with index 0

i want array like :

```
const category = [
{
  name: 'Groceries',
  icon: ICONS.GROCERY,
  color:"red"
},
{
  name: 'Bakery',
  icon: ICONS.BAKERY,
  color:"pink"
},
{
  name: 'General Stores',
  icon: ICONS.GENERAL_STORE,
  color:"blue"
},
{
  name: 'Cafe & Food',
  icon: ICONS.CAFE,
  color:"green"
},
{
  name: 'Cafe & Food',
  icon: ICONS.CAFE,
  color:"red"
},
{
  name: 'Apparels',
  icon: ICONS.APPARELS,
  color:"pink"
},

 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .

];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. (Be sure to make your title a summary of your problem, not just the opening sentence of your question.)

Answer (score 1):

To get circular index you can use [remainder operator (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) where max index is the length of colors array:

```js
categories.map((category, index) => {
  const circularIndex = index % bgColors.length
  return {...category, color: bgColors[circularIndex] }
})
```

Comment: yaaa, it works, thanku sooo much :)